# Question about "running times" of a for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I started reading the book "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition", and I've encountered something that isn't clear enough for me, about "insertion-sort" algorithm.

Please have a look at the pic first:

[image: Click Here]

First of all, the author defined n = **A.length**.  **A.length** is the length of array A.

So, let's say the length of array "A" is 5. If I run a **for** loop from j = 2 (like in the picture) to A.Length = 5, I would say that the first row will run 4 times, meaning it will run n - 1 times for any n. On the other hand, the author writes that the first row will run n times.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The first row likely refers to the number of times the condition is checked. If your loop runs `n-1` times, the condition on the iterator is checked `n` times (including at the end, when it becomes false). Inside the loop body, all statements have been marked with `n-1`, as expected.

Comment: You are a champ.

Comment: @OneWhoAsksSomeQuestions If this satisfactorily answers your question, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This n may express time-complexity -> O(n^2) of the outer for-loop the insertion-sort has and not its actual loop-count.